# Using Request within Eloquent Model Observer

Tags: php, laravel, request, observers

In Laravel 5.3, we're trying to create a form, which the user can update their profile details, including a new password.

However we want to only set the password if its been submitted.

We're using a CRUD framework which handles the updating of the models, and we don't want to roll our own `update(Request $request)` method.

We're aware that you can register model observers similar to

```
User::created(function(User $user){

});
```

We were hoping to achieve something similar to

```
User::created(function(User $user){

    if( $request->has('password') ){
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
    }

});
```

However, when we access $request, its completely empty. e.g if we do `dd($request->all());` its an empty array, however if we dump out `dd($_POST);` we get everything.

I assume this is because of the order things are loaded, and the request system hasn't yet loaded.

Is there a way we can get the request without accessing the `$_POST` directly?

Thanks

Comment: What is the point of this?, laravel uses bcrypt to hash passwords out of the box.

Comment: Read the question again and it might make sense, seems everybody else understood :D

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Laravel 5.3+**

[`request()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-request) helper should work for you:

```
if (request()->has('password')) {
    $user->password = bcrypt(request()->password);
}
```

You can access property with:

```
request()->password
request()->get('password')
request('password')
```

**Lumen 5.3+**

The `request()` helper is not available in Lumen so you will need to use the IoC container.

`app('Illuminate\Http\Request')`

Example:

`if (app('Illuminate\Http\Request')->has('password')) {
    $user->password = bcrypt(app('Illuminate\Http\Request')->password);
}`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`request`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-request) helper fuction as:

```
if( request()->has('password') ){
    $user->password = bcrypt(request()->get('password'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the other two answers, you can pass the request through to the function:

```
User::created(function(User $user) use ($request) {
```